# Microsoft Edge: Distinguish Desktop vs. Surface/Touch

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent, microsoft-edge

Short but apparently tricky question:
How can I distinguish Microsoft Edge browser on Desktop from Surface-Tablets in Javascript?

Edge on Windows 10 has shows user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
```

As far as my research turned out, user agent on a Surface device is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
```

So the only difference seems to be "Win64; x64", but I can't rely on that, since it only shows the current CPU architecture, right?

My concern is: I am working on a web application, which offers some special menu entries for touch devices, since they don't recognize a double click or right mouse button. So on iOS/Android I can easily figure that out, but for Win10 mobile vs. desktop it is difficult.

Do you have any other hints on how to distinguish these to environments?

Comment: Why do you need to know? That will help us provide possible solutions

Comment: Thanks, you asked. My concern is: I am working on a web application, which offers some special menu entries for touch devices, since they don't recognize a double click or right mouse button. So on iOS/Android I can easily figure that out, but for Win10 mobile vs. desktop it is difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have wrong ***User Agent*** string for mobile devices:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android ; ; ) AppleWebKit/ (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ Mobile Safari/ Edge/.

It is available at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Well, my quoted Surface user agent is actually derived from a Trekstor Windows 10 Surftab, which a friend of mine owns.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile devices contains some events that browsers in desktop dont

You can use something like this function

```
function isTouch() {  
  var touch = false;
  try {  
    document.createEvent("TouchEvent");  
    touch = true;
  } catch (e) {}  
  return touch;
}
```

Comment: There are laptops with a touch screen for which such assumptions fail :( I learned this the hardway

Comment: That's quite right, but on these devices, a user should use the mouse as an input device, since my application is primarily designed for desktop based customers.

Comment: In fact I use Modernizr's approach to distinguish touch browsers (`return !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window)`), but that doesn't distinguish between IE11/Edge desktop and Surface/tablet.